# Refactoring case statements with "with" statements

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a triple nested to case statement. It's a complete abomination going on in this controller action.

But, I'm happy that I'm in this situation because IMO one of the best ways to learn is seeing code do the same thing in many different approaches. That leads me to this question.

How can I refactor this bit of code to use `with` statements instead of `case`? All of the examples I'm finding online are more trivial that this example.

#### CODE:

```
   case Nba.get_todays_games do
      {:ok, games} ->
        game_id = Map.get(games, "games")
          |> Enum.random
          |> Map.get("id")
          :timer.sleep(1000)

      case Nba.get_game_summary(game_id) do
        {:ok, game} ->
          team_id = Map.take(game, ["away", "home"])
            |> Enum.random
            |> elem(1)
            |> Map.get("id")
            :timer.sleep(1000)

        case Nba.get_team_roster(team_id) do
          {:ok, team} ->
            player_id   = Map.get(team, "players")
              |> Enum.random
              |> Map.get("id")

            player_name = Map.get(team, "players")
              |> Enum.find(fn %{"id" => id} -> player_id == id end)
              |> Map.get("full_name")
        end
      end
    end
```

I've noticed that I simply can't refactor like this:

```
with {:ok, games} <- Nba.get_todays_games,  
     {:ok, game}  <- Nba.get_todays_games(game_id),
     {:ok, team}  <- Nba.get_team_roster(team_id)
```

I obviously need to do the logic in between to get the game_id and team_id. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just intersperse the `with` clauses with what you need to evaluate, and you are all set:

```
with {:ok, games} <- Nba.get_todays_games,
     game_id <- evaluate_game_id(),
     {:ok, game}  <- Nba.get_todays_games(game_id),
     team_id <- evaluate_team_id(),
     {:ok, team}  <- Nba.get_team_roster(team_id)
```

My advice would be to extract evaluation inside separate private functions to increase the readability.

Comment: ah I see. So, I would make the evaluate_game_id function below. That looks super nice!

Comment: Generally speaking, you aren’t obliged to extract anything to functions, the ugly superlong pipelines are indeed permitted as well :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help. I really like the with statement so far.

Comment: You can use `=` in `game_id` and `team_id` as these will always match.

Answer (score 4):

You can put assignment or other statements in between the `<-` ones, just make sure to separate them with a comma.

```
with {:ok, games} <- Nba.get_todays_games,
     game_id = Map.get(games, "games")
       |> Enum.random
       |> Map.get("id"),
     :timer.sleep(1000),
     {:ok, game} <- Nba.get_game_summary(game_id),
     ...,
     do: ...
```